# Passing objects from a javascript function to Asp .net Controller function

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I have js function that creates a pdf using html2canvas. Now I want to pass this pdf to my asp .net controller so that I can send this pdf as an email attachment. Any idea how to do this?

here is the js

```
function getPDF() {

        var HTML_Width = $(".canvas_div_pdf").width();
        var HTML_Height = $(".canvas_div_pdf").height();
        var top_left_margin = 15;
        var PDF_Width = HTML_Width + (top_left_margin * 2);
        var PDF_Height = (PDF_Width * 1.5) + (top_left_margin * 2);
        var canvas_image_width = HTML_Width;
        var canvas_image_height = HTML_Height;

        var totalPDFPages = Math.ceil(HTML_Height / PDF_Height) - 1;


        html2canvas($(".canvas_div_pdf")[0], { allowTaint: true }).then(function (canvas) {
            canvas.getContext('2d');

            console.log(canvas.height + "  " + canvas.width);


            var imgData = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 1.0);
            var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', [PDF_Width, PDF_Height]);
            pdf.addImage(imgData, 'JPG', top_left_margin, top_left_margin, canvas_image_width, canvas_image_height);


            for (var i = 1; i <= totalPDFPages; i++) {
                pdf.addPage(PDF_Width, PDF_Height);
                pdf.addImage(imgData, 'JPG', top_left_margin, -(PDF_Height * i) + (top_left_margin * 4), canvas_image_width, canvas_image_height);
            }

            pdf.save("HTML-Document.pdf");
        });
    };
```

right now this function just saves the pdf if I make an appropriate button in the view.

here is the view.

```
@model List<GMASchoolProject.Models.Timetable>

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Timetable";
}



<div class="canvas_div_pdf">
@if (Model != null)
{
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                <th>
                    Time | Day
                </th>

                @foreach (var day in ViewBag.Days)
                {
                    <th>
                        @day
                    </th>
                }
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
            {
                var temp_time = Model[i].Ti_start;
                var flag = 0;
                var temp = i;
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        @Model[i].Ti_start
                        -
                        @Model[i].Ti_end
                    </th>
                    <td>
                        @if (Model[i].Ti_day == "Monday" && Model[i] != null)
                        {
                            if (Model[i].Ti_cl_fk_id != null)
                            {
                                @Model[i].Class.Cl_name
                            }
                            if (i != Model.Count - 1)
                            {
                                if (Model[i].Ti_start == Model[i + 1].Ti_start)
                                {
                                    flag++;
                                    i++;
                                }
                            }

                        }
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @if (Model[i].Ti_day == "Tuesday" || flag == 1 && Model[i] != null)
                        {
                            if (Model[i].Ti_cl_fk_id != null)
                            {
                                @Model[i].Class.Cl_name
                            }

                            if (i != Model.Count - 1)
                            {
                                if (Model[i].Ti_start == Model[i + 1].Ti_start)
                                {
                                    flag++;
                                    i++;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @if (Model[i].Ti_day == "Wednesday" || flag == 2 && Model[i] != null)
                        {
                            if (Model[i].Ti_cl_fk_id != null)
                            {
                                @Model[i].Class.Cl_name
                            }

                            if (i != Model.Count - 1)
                            {
                                if (Model[i].Ti_start == Model[i + 1].Ti_start)
                                {
                                    flag++;
                                    i++;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @if (Model[i].Ti_day == "Thursday" || flag == 3 && Model[i] != null)
                        {
                            if (Model[i].Ti_cl_fk_id != null)
                            {
                                @Model[i].Class.Cl_name
                            }

                            if (i != Model.Count - 1)
                            {
                                if (Model[i].Ti_start == Model[i + 1].Ti_start)
                                {
                                    flag++;
                                    i++;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @if (Model[i].Ti_day == "Friday" || flag == 4 && Model[i] != null)
                        {
                            if (Model[i].Ti_cl_fk_id != null)
                            {
                                @Model[i].Class.Cl_name
                            }

                            if (i != Model.Count - 1)
                            {
                                if (Model[i].Ti_start == Model[i + 1].Ti_start)
                                {
                                    flag++;
                                    i++;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @if (Model[i].Ti_day == "Saturday" || flag == 5 && Model[i] != null)
                        {
                            if (Model[i].Ti_cl_fk_id != null)
                            {
                                @Model[i].Class.Cl_name
                            }

                            if (i != Model.Count - 1)
                            {
                                if (Model[i].Ti_start == Model[i + 1].Ti_start)
                                {
                                    flag++;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    </td>
                </tr>

            }

        </tbody>
    </table>
}
```

and this is the controller fuunction.

```
public ActionResult SendMail(int? id)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
          
            var students = db.Students.ToList();

            List<String> mails = new List<String>();
            

            foreach (var item in students)
            {
                
                if (Request.Form[item.St_id.ToString()] == null)
                {
                    continue;
                }
                mails.Add(item.St_email);

            }
          pdf= object from js function
            foreach (var maili in mails)
        {
            using (MailMessage mail = new MailMessage())
            {
                //var ma = "syedzaidi7684@gmail.com";
                mail.From = new MailAddress("razaabbas768@gmail.com");
                mail.To.Add(new MailAddress(maili));
                mail.Subject = "GMA Timetable";
                mail.Body = "<h2>Timetable</h2>";
                mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
                mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(new MemoryStream(myPdfAsBytes), "Timetable.pdf"));

                using (SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587))
                {
                    smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("razaabbas768@gmail.com", "password");
                    smtp.EnableSsl = true;
                    smtp.Send(mail);
                }
            }

        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Classes");     

        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Students");
        
    }
```

Comment: Use [`pdf.output('datauristring');`](https://medium.com/@weihui.guo/save-html-page-and-online-images-as-a-pdf-attachment-with-one-click-from-client-side-21d65656e764)

Answer (score 0):

Convert it's into bytearray or base64 string(or hold in viewbag) and send to controller and then again convert back to pdf in controller (just google for bytearray or base64 string to pdf in .NET)